# postgres's alternative for "fetch_status"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question, I need an alternative to "fetch_STATUS". I have to translate the next block of code from Sql Servers to Postgres.

```
   WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
       BEGIN
        IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
            BEGIN
            IF (@OrdenSecuencial = '' OR LOWER(@OrdenSecuencial) = 'null' OR @OrdenSecuencial IS NULL)
            BEGIN
                Exec SPUpdateSecuencial @ArbolNodoID, @OrdenSecuencial output
                IF @@ERROR <> 0 Goto DeleteError
            END
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM CU_ArbolNodo INTO @ArbolNodoID,@Orden, @OrdenSecuencial,@ArbolNodoIdPadre
       END
```

Comment: Have you read the Postgres cursors documentation? (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)

Comment: I have doubt. I need to make an if condition where fetch_status is diferent to -2.

Comment: What does `@@fetch_status = 2` mean? Which condition indicates that?

Comment: `@@fetch_status = -2` means that the fetched row is missing..

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server:

```
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)  
           BEGIN  
                IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
```

In PostgreSQL:

```
    WHILE (FOUND) LOOP  
           BEGIN  
                IF (FOUND)   
                  [...]  
                END IF;  
           END;  
       END LOOP;
```

I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39966688/6934093

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for result_row in (select ArbolNodoID, OrdenSecuencial
                   from some_table) 
loop
   if (lower(result_row.OrdenSecuencial) in ('', 'null') or result_row.OrdenSecuencial is null) then 
     perform SPUpdateSecuencial(result_row.ArbolNodoID, result_row.OrdenSecuencial);
   end if;
end loop;
```

I don't know what the  `output` keyword in T-SQL is supposed to do when calling the stored procedure.